# MYSQL: How to display data if foreign key is implode (',')

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on creating MySQL queries. I have two tables, which are user and factory. The data and structure are as below:

1. table user

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHuki.png)

2. table factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkC8o.png)

From table user, u can see example, id = 1 got factoryID =  2,3. At table factory, id = 2 is F1 and id = 3 is F2.

Now, how i want to join the table, and display the data like example,

```
user.id = 1

user.name = Amira

user.factoryID = 2,3

factory.factoryName = F1,F2
```

Can anyone know how to write the query?

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: That is a bad table design. You should read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest fixing your table design. Using [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can do the trick, but you will be facing some performance issues, especially for larger data.

As per the question you could use:

```
select user.id,name,factoryID,group_concat(factoryName) as factoryName
from user  
inner join factory  ON FIND_IN_SET(factory.id,user.factoryID)
group by user.id,name,factoryID;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    name    factoryID   factoryName
> 1    Armira      2,3         F1,F2
> 2    Balqis      4,5         F3,F4
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a39e9ab328fc1b6a93fc359d9f690525)